# How to hold alert dialog till Ok click in android

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog

I have a login screen, when in click on login button then a pop up is displaying with Ok.
My need is to hold the pop up till Ok click.

Comment: use setCancelable(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
    public static void showMessageDialogWithIntent(final Activity activity, String Message, final String intentClassName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Log.e(TAG, "showMessageDialogWithIntent");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setMessage(Message).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            try {
                // do work here
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Comment: setCancelable(false) will prevent the user not to terminate the dialogue unless he clicks OK, isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This is way:

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Hello ,");

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             alertDialog.cancel();
            }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using 
`setCancelable(false)` like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Some Message");
    builder.setTitle("You Title");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //I won't add finish() here
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
```